# Setting zoom dynamically level in Google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application where I have to set the zoom level dynamically when the distance between two points increases. How can I implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`setZoom()`](http://goo.gl/ekaN4) or [`zoomIn()`](http://goo.gl/xorPP) or [`zoomOut()`](http://goo.gl/9usKD) on the `MapController` you get from your `MapView`.

Comment: Yeah using these we zoom level but I want do it dynamically we distance between the two points increase then I have set zoom level dynamically.